# Routes going through api.php returning unauthorised whereas the same route going through web.php works

Tags: php, laravel, api, axios, middleware

I have a page which enables users to create 'folders'. I'm using the function below to getAll folders belonging to each user, so when a user logs in they should see all of their folders but not the folders of other users.

```
/**
 * Retrieve all user folders
 *
 * @return Response
 */
public function getAll()
{
    // notes associated to folder included
    return Folder::where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->get();
}
```

This is what the vue page used to load all folders looks like:

```
<template>
    <v-app id="inspire">
        <v-card v-for="folder in folders" :key="folder.id">
            <v-card-text>
                Name: {{ folder.name }}
            </v-card-text>
        </v-card>
    </v-app>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from "vuex";

export default {
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['folders'])
    },

    mounted() {
        this.$store.dispatch('getAllFolders');
    }
};
</script>
```

This is what the getAllFolders method looks like:

```
getAllFolders() {
    apiClient.get(window.routes['folders.getAll'])
    .then(function(response){
        console.log(response)
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.error(error);
    });
},
```

Adding the route to web.php works and allows for each user to see their relevant folders:

```
Route::get('folders/get-all', 'FolderController@getAll')->name('folders.getAll');
```

However adding it to api.php leads to unauthorised errors:

```
  Route::middleware(['auth:api'])->group(function () {     
      Route::get('folders/get-all', 'FolderController@getAll')->name('folders.getAll');
      Route::apiResource('folders', FolderController::class);
});
```

[image]

What might I be doing wrong?

Comment: are you passing some token with each request?

Comment: Yes a X-XSRF-TOKEN is present in the header

Comment: that isn't an authentication token ... the 'api' guard is expecting some type of token to authenticate the user with

Comment: The user table has an api_token column which is present for each user?

Comment: okay, then you would need to be sending that token with every request to the api

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Api routes are stateless, they are designed for requests coming from 3rd parties and will require an auth token, which you can generate using a package like Laravel Sanctum.

See: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/sanctum#api-token-authentication

If you are doing ajax requests from your own front end then this is adding unneeded complexity. Stick to `web.php`, which does not apply the api middleware, and add your own prefex so you can tell apart your html and ajax end points. Ie `'/data/user_folders'`.